# How to ensure scheduled tasks run in single instance

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduler-job

We have one CD app service with multiple scaled instances. We observed the scheduler job is executing in all instances parallelly. Post enabling Async also we noticed its running on all instances. Any other way we can disable this not to run on all instances? Have to run scheduled job only on CD server and only on one instance.

Comment: There's a configuration for the agent that runs. You could disable it on some of the CD instances.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest extracting the scheduler job code out of CD instance into a serverless function which can scale very easily and more controllable. Even from a cost perspective, it is not that much.